# Postgresql query does not work as intended after I add JOIN to it

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I make a query like this:

```
SELECT payment.customer_id, COUNT(payment.customer_id), SUM(payment.amount)
FROM payment 
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY SUM(payment.amount) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

it works perfectly, but when i try to join a field from another table, it fails:

```
SELECT payment.customer_id, customer.email COUNT(payment.customer_id), SUM(payment.amount)
FROM payment 
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY SUM(payment.amount) DESC
LIMIT 10
JOIN customer
ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id
```

What do i do wrong? How to add the email column from customer table?

Comment: `JOIN` is part of the `FROM` clause. If you want to apply the LIMIT before the join move it into a Derived Table.

Comment: Try to put the join part between from and group by

Answer (score 0):

For joining you have to use it after From keyword only like below one

```
Select Table1.customer_id,Table1.email,Table1.amt from (
SELECT payment.customer_id, customer.email COUNT(payment.customer_id) email, SUM(payment.amount) amt
FROM payment 
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY SUM(payment.amount) DESC
LIMIT 10
) Table1 JOIN customer
ON Table1.customer_id = customer.customer_id
```

Comment: Thanks! What is Table1 in your answer?

Comment: It's a alias name for the inner query

Comment: Thank a lot, i've got the principle now

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced the `JOIN`; it belongs in the `FROM` clause. There is also a comma missing in your `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.email, COUNT(p.payment_id), SUM(p.amount)
FROM customer c
JOIN payment p ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id
ORDER BY SUM(p.amount) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

See that I switched tables in `FROM` and `JOIN`. This is not necessary, but feels a bit better in my opinion, saying: give me the customers with their payment data. Switch to `LEFT JOIN` if you want customers without payment data, too.